# Drives shared on network without action

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, smb

I've started a new job and was given a workstation.
The computer runs Windows 10 Pro but it is not part of a domain and is configured with a personal account (noone but me knows the username/password).

I've noticed that everytime i come in to work my drives (SSD + HDD) are shared on the network and accessible by everyone.

I doubt that anyone has been accessing my computer when i'm not at work (enabled audit logging), and i doubt they have installed any kind of keylogging software/RAT.

What do you think could be the cause of this issue?

Drive D Icon

[image: enter ydescription here]

---

Properties->Sharing

[image]

---

Sharing Settings

[image]

Edit: The Pc is a Dell Inspiron 5680 that came with Windows 10 Pro.
I'm starting to doubt it could be some weird Local Policy set up by dell?

Comment: Are they shared via "folder sharing"? How did you find out that they're accessible by everyone?

Comment: Edited with images

Comment: Ah, so it's a custom share – not the built-in administrative `d$` share? Have you tried asking your local IT team if they've done this? Have you tried enabling audit logging for the registry changes to LanmanServer? (Note that 'Everyone' in this specific field doesn't automatically grant access, clients must still have an account and must be allowed by file/folder permissions.)

Comment: Enabled audit logging. Also running an offline scan of both drives for additional security.

Comment: @grawity A short while after a reboot, i found the drives shared once again.
Yet the logs are empty. Could this be a side effect of running Docker or Hyper-V?
Also, when i disable sharing an alert pops up that x users are connected to the drive.

Comment: So... which users are connected? Check via fsmgmt.msc, `net session`, or `psfile`.

Comment: Looks like i'm the only one connected. Also, the share permissions have changed and now i'm the only user with access to it.